# SQL Server : compare the column COUNT of purchased products to UNSOLD products

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, compare

I am really sorry if I'm asking a dump question, I am trying to achieve the following task: "Write a query to list only those products (p_id, p_name, cat_name) that have never been purchased."

I have 2 tables:

- `ProductCategory` (p_id, p_name, cat_id, cat_name, cat_description )
- `CustomerPreference` (cust_id, cust_name, pp_id(purchasedproduct), rating )

So I was trying to write the query both performing `COUNT(p_id) FROM ProductCategory` and a `COUNT(pp_id) FROM CustomerPreference`, so that I could compare them and list only those products that were not sold.

```
SELECT 
    PC.p_id, PC.p_name, PC.cat_name, COUNT(PC.p_id) AS no_of_purchases
FROM 
    ProductCategory PC, CustomerPreference CP
WHERE 
    PC.p_id = CP.pp_id
GROUP BY 
    PC.p_id, PC.p_name, PC.cat_name, PC.p_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(CP.pp_id) NOT IN COUNT(PC.p_id)
ORDER BY 
    no_of_purchases
```

I know my syntax is wrong in this query, but I hope you can see the logic of what I try to achieve, I would greatly appreciate if you could advise how can I display the column of products(p_id) that were not sold.

Comment: the first question that needs to be answered..how do you identify a purchased product?

Comment: pp_id from CustomerPreferences table, contains the same value as in p_id from PoductCategory table. So that's why I was trying to count all the products ids I have and then compare/substract the count of purchased products

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rows from one table (`ProductCategory`) that do not exist in another table (`CustomerPreference`), you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT pc.*
FROM ProductCategory pc
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM CustomerPreference
        WHERE pp_id = pc.p_id
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, for your solution and explanation, helped me to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

The products that never appear in the CustomerPreference table would be:

```
SELECT PC.p_id, PC.p_name, PC.cat_name
FROM ProductCategory PC
LEFT JOIN CustomerPreference CP
ON PC.p_id = CP.pp_id
WHERE CP.pp_id IS NULL
ORDER BY PC.p_name
```

Comment: Thanks for help, one question: since I don't have a column "no_of_purchases" in any of the tables, how can I alter the query to create one.          as for example when I do COUNT(p_id) AS no_of_purchases

Comment: @AlexVahrushev Sorry, it was a mistake to order by that - I have corrected my answer.  In this query all of the no_of_purchases would be zero.